# Excel 2016: How to change width of every line in a chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a couple of charts with 20+ series, and every time I have to put them in different presentations or emails I have to go about changing the line width manually, which consumes an enormous amount of time. Do you know of a way to change the size of all lines at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: With "*line*", do you perhaps mean row or column, and change width to fit the entered value in the cells? If so, do you want to change them all at once to the same size, or do you just want them to change accordingly to content?

Comment: Hi, with "line" I mean the literal lines that are inside charts. For instance, if I have a set of data and I decide to graph them in a line chart (ALT+N+N)